# Responsive navbar with dropdown not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on creating a responsive navbar that has a dropdown in it. Below is my code:

I have the CSS code and media queries inline for testing purpose. So it might look lengthy.

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="../../themes/bootstrap/starterkits/THEMENAME/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<style type="text/css">body {margin:0;font-family:Arial}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.home {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.topnav a {
  float: right;
  display: block;
  color: #000000;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: right;
  overflow: hidden;
}



.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 17px;    
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.topnav a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #555;
  color: #D5DBDB;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child), .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown {float: none;}
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown-content {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
</style>
<div class="panel">
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
<div class="home"><a href="#"><img src="../../sites/default/files/logo_0.png" /></a></div>

<div class="dropdown">
<div class="dropbtn"><a href="#">Programs</a></div>

<div class="dropdown-content"><a href="#">Success</a></div>
</div>
<a href="#">Contact</a> 
<a href="#">Families</a> 
<a href="#">About</a> 
<a class="icon" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myFunction()" style="font-size:15px;">☰</a></div>
</div>
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
</script>
```

The menu contains the Home logo image at the left and 4 menu items on the right.

After the active 'home' link is the 'Programs' drop-button that should have a dropdown 'Success' underneath it. This dropdown is not loading correctly and the design is distorted. Any help to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need your dropdown button to be a `div` tag, it should be a `button` tag.

So change

`<div class="dropbtn"><a href="#">Programs</a></div>`

to

`<button class="dropbtn"><a style="padding: 0px" href="#">Programs</a></button>`

This should the drop-down load correctly and inline with the other items in the navbar. Hopefully this helps you get on the right track without changing most of your original code.

```css
.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.home {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.topnav a {
  float: right;
  display: block;
  color: #000000;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: right;
  overflow: hidden;
}



.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 17px;    
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.topnav a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #555;
  color: #D5DBDB;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child), .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown {float: none;}
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown-content {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="../../themes/bootstrap/starterkits/THEMENAME/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<style type="text/css">body {margin:0;font-family:Arial}
</style>
<div class="panel">
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
<div class="home"><a href="#"><img src="../../sites/default/files/logo_0.png" /></a></div>

<div class="dropdown">
<button class="dropbtn"><a style="padding: 0px" href="#">Programs</a></button>
<div class="dropdown-content"><a href="#">Success</a></div>
</div>
<a href="#">Contact</a> 
<a href="#">Families</a> 
<a href="#">About</a> 
<a class="icon" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myFunction()" style="font-size:15px;">☰</a></div>
</div>
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: This solution works, because the a-tag as well as the surrounding div had a padding which summed up.

Comment: I firstly wondered why just using the button was not destroying the absolute positioned dropdown content. But this was due to the float of the a-tag.

Comment: I added the <a> tag because I need the 'Programs' menu to get redirected to a page. how can that be achieved?

Comment: @Rick I've updated my answer to include the `a` tag. I added it back but just took away the padding to make all the items stay inline on the navbar since the `a` tag adds extra padding by default.

Comment: @King11 Thanks a lot!!! this is working perfectly well for me!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest not to use floats for layouting. Flexboxes are much better for that and are widely supported in browsers these days.

The floats are breaking the flow of your html elements.

Furthermore there was a padding on the .dropbtn, which made the items not being in line.

```css
body {
        margin:0;
        font-family:Arial
      }

      .topnav {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: flex-end;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #ffffff;
      }

      .home {
        margin-right: auto;
      }

      .topnav a {
        display: block;
        color: #000000;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 17px;
      }

      .active {
        background-color: #4CAF50;
        color: white;
      }

      .topnav .icon {
        display: none;
      }

      .dropdown {
        overflow: hidden;
      }

      .dropdown .dropbtn {
        font-size: 17px;    
        border: none;
        outline: none;
        color: black;
        background-color: inherit;
        margin: 0;
      }

      .dropdown-content {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        min-width: 160px;
        box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        z-index: 1;
      }

      .dropdown-content a {
        color: black;
        padding: 12px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
        text-align: left;
      }

      .topnav a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
        background-color: #555;
        color: #D5DBDB;
      }

      .dropdown-content a:hover {
        background-color: #ddd;
        color: black;
      }

      .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
        display: block;
      }

      @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
        .topnav a:not(:first-child), .dropdown .dropbtn {
          display: none;
        }
        .topnav a.icon {
          display: block;
        }
      }

      @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
        .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
        .topnav.responsive .icon {
          position: absolute;
          right: 0;
          top: 0;
        }
        .topnav.responsive a {
          display: block;
          text-align: left;
        }
        .topnav.responsive .dropdown {float: none;}
        .topnav.responsive .dropdown-content {position: relative;}
        .topnav.responsive .dropdown .dropbtn {
          display: block;
          width: 100%;
          text-align: left;
        }
      }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../../themes/bootstrap/starterkits/THEMENAME/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="panel">
      <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
        <div class="home">
          <a href="#">
            <img src="../../sites/default/files/logo_0.png" />
          </a>
        </div>

        <a href="#">About</a> 
        <a href="#">Families</a> 
        <a href="#">Contact</a> 

        <div class="dropdown">
          <div class="dropbtn">
            <a href="#">Programs</a>
          </div>
          
          <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="#">Success</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <a class="icon" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myFunction()" style="font-size:15px;">☰</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script>
      function myFunction() {
        var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
        if (x.className === "topnav") {
          x.className += " responsive";
        } else {
          x.className = "topnav";
        }
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```